# Why is the new outlet not receiving any power

Tags: electrical

I am replacing a not GFCI outlet with a GFCI.  There is no grounding wire that I can see.  When I connect everything, the status light is green which I would assume that everything should be connected properly.  However, when I plug something into the outlet, there is no power.  I know that what I plugged in is working properly as I checked it with a different outlet.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you connect to the Line side or the Load side of the outlet?

Comment: Include some closeups of your wired outlet... both sides.

Comment: Try tripping it and resetting it. No clue on the light, I have some that glow when on others that glow when tripped.

Comment: I've certainly had ones that needed to be reset the first time they were powered up. Line .vs. Load is another common issue, particularly if the wiring continues from the outlet to elsewhere (rather than one cable to just this outlet) and you did not establish which wire was the power feed first.

Comment: yeah, could be misuse of Load terminals.  Since the goal is to protect this outlet only, Load should not be used at all.